# Как вытащить значение Boolean из метода

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    question("Текст к вопросу...");
    /* сюда нужно написать какой-то код, 
    вытягивающий переменную right_answer из метода question.
    как получить значение right_answer? */
}

static void question (string text, int right_answer_num) 
{
    bool right_answer = false;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int answer_num = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
    if (answer_num == right_answer_num) 
    {
        right_answer = true;
        Console.WriteLine("YAY!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно организовать возврат параметра (или нескольких) с помощью [ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/14akc2c7.aspx) или [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/t3c3bfhx.aspx).

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int right_answer_num = 1;
    bool right_answer = false;
    question("Текст к вопросу...", right_answer_num, ref right_answer);
    // теперь в right_answer хранится полученное в методе question значение.
}

static void question(string text, int right_answer_num, ref bool right_answer)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int answer_num = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
    if (answer_num == right_answer_num)
    {
        right_answer = true;
        Console.WriteLine("YAY!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

В C# не предусмотренно возможности доступа к локальным переменным функций. Мало того, все локальные переменные хранятся в стэке, и после вызова функции уничтожаются. Однако, в данном случае нет необходимости доступа к локальным переменным. Используйте возврат значения с помощью ключевого слова `return` :

```
    static void Main() 
    {
        var res = question("Текст к вопросу...", 123);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine("YAY!");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Wrong answer");
    }

    static bool question (string text, int right_answer_num) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        string answer = Console.ReadLine();
        return right_answer_num == Convert.ToInt32(answer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте поля класса:

```
private static bool _right_answer;

static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    question("Текст к вопросу...");
    /* получаем значение right_answer */
    Console.WriteLine(_right_answer);
}

static void question (string text, int right_answer_num) 
{
    _right_answer = false;
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    int answer_num = Convert.ToInt32(answer);
    if (answer_num == right_answer_num) 
    {
        _right_answer = true;
        Console.WriteLine("YAY!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Формально верное решение, но я бы советовал по возможности воздерживаться от добавления в классы полей, играющих роль выходных параметров для методов. Засорять классы лишними полями не имеет смысла.